# Access / DCount gives a TExt field and not INT field?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010, I have two tables 'Contact' and 'PhoneCalls'.

I created this Query for 'Contact' as I want to see how many times I called a contact.

**Query:**

```
SELECT Contact.*, DCount("[ID]","ColdCall"," [ColdCall]![ContactID]   = " & [Contact.ID]) AS Call
FROM Contact
```

I have build this query using the following expression:

```
Call: DCount("[ID]","ColdCall"," [ColdCall]![ContactID]   = " & [Contact.ID])
```

It works fine except that it creates a TEXT field instead of a NUMBER field.  For instance, I need to sort this query out, but I can only sort it "A to Z" and not "smallest to largest" as it should be.

Do you have any idea on how I can solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CInt() to force the call count to be an integer:

```
SELECT Contact.*, CInt(DCount("[ID]","ColdCall"," [ColdCall]![ContactID]   = " & [Contact.ID])) AS Call
FROM Contact;
```

Note also that using DCount() in this way is rather inefficient. If that approach works to your satisfaction then continue to use it for now, but don't be surprised if it starts to bog down as the tables grow.

Comment: Hi Gord, that fix my problem, thanks a lot.
When you say "rather inefficient", do you mean that I should also use CInt() in another way? Can you give me an example, I would prefer to follow the most standard way :-)  Thanks a lot for your help!